# glossaries package conditional formatting of SOME labels

Tags: glossaries, italic

I am writing my thesis in biology in memoir class using glossaries package. Acronyms for long gene names is written in two forms: the symbol is in italic form when the gene on DNA is mentioned, and it's in normal text when the protein form is mentioned. something like below:

```
\newcommand{\glsgene} etc
if \glsgene{
    print(full name (italic `short'))
    add label to the acronym list
} else{
    \gls as usual
}
```

I have explained this in following MWE. How do I code this in latex? Thanks you SO MUCH!

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 12 pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[acronym,nomain,nonumberlist]{glossaries}  
\makeglossaries
\glsdisablehyper %disables links 
\newacronym{RING}{RING}{really interesting new gene}
\begin{document}
\newpage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\hrule

Current acronym style: \gls{RING}

To refer to RING gene on DNA, it should be printed as `really interesting new gene (\textit{RING})'. Please note that the full name is in normal text whereas the symbol/short name is in italics.

When I mean RING in the protein form, it should be printed as `really interesting new gene (RING)' --- everything in normal text.

Of course, I have to specify what form I am referring to when using it for the first time. But the entry should be automatically included in the acronym list regardless of DNA or protein versions, so I don't miss any acronyms. Maybe some sort of 'if'

The full name in the list of acronyms will be printed in normal text regardless of DNA or protein form. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Should `\glsgene` always use the long and short form (even if it's already been used)? Or should it work like `\gls` and only show the long form on first use and just show the italic short form on next use?

Comment: No, full name only first time, but I would like the flexibility of choosing italic or normal text version for each subsequent use, which I can manage pretty easily with \textit{} as long as I know it has been previously defined. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MWE below defines `\glsgene` to temporarily change `\acronymfont` to `\textit` before using `\gls`. The change is localised with braces. This needs to have the `long-short` style set to ensure `\acronymfont` is used to format the short form. (This just does its argument by default.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 12 pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[acronym,nomain,nonumberlist]{glossaries}  
\makeglossaries
\glsdisablehyper %disables links 

\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\newacronym{RING}{RING}{really interesting new gene}

\newcommand{\glsgene}[2][]{{\let\acronymfont\textit\gls[#1]{#2}}}

\begin{document}
\newpage
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\hrule

First use: \gls{RING}.

Next use: \gls{RING}, \glsgene{RING}.

Reset\glsresetall

First use: \glsgene{RING}.

Next use: \glsgene{RING}, \gls{RING}.

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: image of result]

Comment: Excellent. Works like a charm. Thank you so much Nicola :)